# react native how to swipe automaticlly with flatlist paging

Tags: react-native, expo

I use flatlist and pagingEnable. if anybody clicks to the color Red, then the flatlist should moving to the picture to red. Is that possible with flatlist & pagingEnable ?

Answer (score 1):

When paging is enebled every items are rendered as page,
use a ref of the flatlist and

```
flatlist.scrollToIndex(index) // or 
flatlist.scrollToItem(item)
```

will do it